# Sql Server Management Studio Express

Tags: sql-server-2005

how do i convert my sql server management studio express to server authentication mode.. please help regarding this..

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean SQL or Mixed-mode Authentication (the ability to login using your SA account). Follow the instructions in [this link](http://www.trap17.com/index.php/Resolving-Can39t-Login-Sqlexpress-Sa-Account_t61695.html).

Comment: Now right click the [MyComputerName]/SQLExpress and select Properties then open the Security page, on Server Authentication section select SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode.

What does this step say.. :s please help..

Comment: there is no page of Security :s

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to connect to it as normal via whatever method you already have (this requires sufficient Admin permissions).

Then to enable access via SQL Logins you can

- Right click on the instance name in Management Studio (mine is `localhost\SQLEXPRESS (SQLServer 10.0.1600)`).
- Go to the `Security` tab.
- Then you should be able to enable SQL Logins by clicking `SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode`.
- Click ok and you're done!

You can now add SQL Logins as connect via them as you would normally.